# Android widget onclick listener

Tags: android, android-widget, onclicklistener

I am trying for the last 2 days to add `onClickListener` to my home screen widget but failed. I have checked all the stackoverflow questions regarding that and tried everything but nothing works.

Please help me. Thanks

`ANameWidget.java`

```
package com.example.saurabhpandey.anamewidget;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;



public class ANameWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {


@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ANameWidget.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.aname_widget_configure);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_text, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);


    }


}

@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // When the user deletes the widget, delete the preference associated with it.
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        ANameWidgetConfigureActivity.deleteTitlePref(context, appWidgetIds[i]);
    }
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
}

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    CharSequence widgetText = ANameWidgetConfigureActivity.loadTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.aname_widget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);


    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }


 }
```

`ANameWidgetConfigureActivity.java`

```
package com.example.saurabhpandey.anamewidget;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class ANameWidgetConfigureActivity extends Activity {

int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
EditText mAppWidgetText;
private static final String PREFS_NAME =   "com.example.saurabhpandey.anamewidget.ANameWidget";
private static final String PREF_PREFIX_KEY = "appwidget_";

public ANameWidgetConfigureActivity() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // Set the result to CANCELED.  This will cause the widget host to cancel
    // out of the widget placement if the user presses the back button.
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

    setContentView(R.layout.aname_widget_configure);
    mAppWidgetText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.appwidget_text);
    findViewById(R.id.add_button).setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);

    // Find the widget id from the intent.
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    // If this activity was started with an intent without an app widget ID, finish with an error.
    if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    mAppWidgetText.setText(loadTitlePref(ANameWidgetConfigureActivity.this, mAppWidgetId));
}

View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Context context = ANameWidgetConfigureActivity.this;

        // When the button is clicked, store the string locally
        String widgetText = mAppWidgetText.getText().toString();
        saveTitlePref(context, mAppWidgetId, widgetText);

        // It is the responsibility of the configuration activity to update the app widget
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        ANameWidget.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);

        // Make sure we pass back the original appWidgetId
        Intent resultValue = new Intent();
        resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
        finish();
    }
};

// Write the prefix to the SharedPreferences object for this widget
static void saveTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId, String text) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefs =  context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
    prefs.putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, text);
    prefs.commit();
}

// Read the prefix from the SharedPreferences object for this widget.
// If there is no preference saved, get the default from a resource
static String loadTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String titleValue = prefs.getString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, null);
    if (titleValue != null) {
        return titleValue;
    } else {
        return context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
    }
}

static void deleteTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefs =            context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
    prefs.remove(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId);
    prefs.commit();
}


}
```

`aname_widget.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appwidget_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="@string/name_widget"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is the error? You should add the error log you got!

Comment: your widget show on screen ?